When fitting a restrictor to the inlet pipe of toilet cistern do i need to cut it to length?
Fitting a SIAMP INTRA COMFORT concealed cistern. How do I fit a restrictor to the inlet pipe (it seems to slide over a plastic locator already in the pipe but seems to be too long)?
